# Disable trash bin for specific folder in owncloud

Tags: owncloud

Is there a way to configure owncloud that files from a specific folder are not moved to the trash bin folder but instead erased immediately? If so, is this possible from web/ftp interface? (I don't have ssh access to the server).

Background: I use a specific folder for rolling backups of my phone. Even though older versions are deleted, they remain in the trash bin and bloat my limited storage space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/configuration/server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#define-trashbin-directory-skip-list) it is possible to set a list of directories to skip in the PHP configuration of ownCloud.

You would add this to the configuration in `$ownCloudRoot/config/config.php`:

```
'trashbin_skip_directories' => ['backupdir'],
```

You can also skip specific file extensions (`trashbin_skip_extensions`) or configure files larger than a given threshold to not go in the trashbin (`trashbin_skip_size_threshold`).

Also note that the default configuration is to keep deleted files for up to 30 days, automatically deleting them when space is needed. The default configuration is also to not use more than half the allocated quota, although this will probably not work well with unlimited quota.